# Excel VBA Replacing Question Mark

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code written up to find and replace question marks in all worksheets in a workbook. However it is not working, can anyone help me out to see where did i go wrong?

```
Sub ReplaceQM()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long

    totalSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    MsgBox totalSheet
    For x = 1 To totalSheet


        lRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(x).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(x).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


        For Z = 1 To lRow
            For i = 1 To lCol

                getPos = InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(x).Cells(Z, i).Value, "~?")

                If getPos > 0 Then

                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(x).Cells(Z, i).Value = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(x).Cells(Z, i).Value, "~?", " ")

                End If

            Next i
        Next Z
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: (a) It successfully replaces `~?` with a space for me.  If you want it to replace all question marks, not just the ones preceded by a tilde, get rid of the tilde in the two spots in your code where you mention it.  (b) If you don't have continuous headings in the first row of each sheet, you will only be replacing until the column prior to the first blank in row 1.  Is that intentional?  (c) Your code will crash if you have any Sheets that are Charts.  You would be better to iterate over `Worksheets` rather than `Sheets`.

Comment: (a) I removed the tilde, and it works fine now. Great, thank you. (b) Yes, it is intentional because there will be a standard template used by all users. (c) I have changed the Sheets to Worksheets as per your advice. Thank you @YowE3K

Comment: I presume you put a `~` in to force Excel to take the next character as a literal. That's the way you replace things like `*` as per this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/214138

Comment: Consider using a Find object instead. It should be faster and it doesn't mess up the inline formatting of your cells as your current code will: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off using Excel's in-range replace function:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook
  ws.UsedRange.Cells.Replace what:="~?", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=False, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next ws
```